# Application of the Phragmén-Lindelöf Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

[image]

Above is an exercise from Conway I am stuck at. I think I have to apply the corollary of the Phragmén-Lindelöf Theorem that is given below. However, the exercise does not provide any information about how the given function $f(z)$ behaves when $|z|$ is sufficiently large. Could anyone help me solve this exercise?

[image]